# Parsing version number from a Java source file

Tags: java, beginner, parsing, groovy, grails

I'm extracting the version number from a file like [this one](https://github.com/arbfranklin/h2database/blob/master/src/main/org/h2/engine/Constants.java). It works, but I find it clumsy and longer than probably needed.

I'd also appreciate some sanity checks as long as they don't make the code noticeably longer (It's just a script, no full Java parser. Something similar to Guava's [getOnlyElement](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement(java.lang.Iterable)) would be nice).

```
version = {->
    def lines = file('src/main/org/h2/engine/Constants.java').readLines();
    def extract = {name ->
        lines.grep {it =~ /public static final int $name =/}[0].replaceFirst(/.*=\s*(\d+);.*/, '$1')
    }
    extract('VERSION_MAJOR') + '.' + extract('VERSION_MINOR') + '.' + extract('BUILD_ID')
}()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only looking for a single occurrence of the variable in the file you could  match the whole file at once. For example like this:

```
version = {->
    def text = file('src/main/org/h2/engine/Constants.java').text
    def extract = {name ->
        nameValue = text.replaceAll(/(?s)^.*public\s+static\s+final\s+int\s+$name\s+=\s*(\d+);.*$/, '$1')
        text.length() == nameValue.length() ? "Cannot find name" : nameValue;
    }
    extract('VERSION_MAJOR') + '.' + extract('VERSION_MINOR') + '.' + extract('BUILD_ID')
}()
```

Instead of getting the lines this script reads the file to one single `String`, and then uses a regular expression to replace the while text with the variable of interest.

In order to do this, we first make sure that the `.` in the regexp will match newlines by adding `(?s)` to the pattern. We then match everything from the start (`^.*`) up until `public static final int $name`, capture the value with `(\d+)`, and then match everything to the end of the file with `.*$`.

Although the regular expression is slightly more involved, this way makes it easier to check whether the replacement has worked and prevents a `NullPointerException`. We can now simply compare the length of the original text with the length of the result. If they are the same the replacement has not succeeded and we can return a custom error-message, otherwise we found the variable of interest.

Comment: Wouldn't `file(…).text` work?

Comment: @200_success Good call, changed it.

Comment: Could you explain what `/(?s)/` does? Also, surely there's a way to do a capturing match instead of a `replaceAll`?

Comment: I have added an explanation for `?s`, don't know about a capturing match. Maybe someone else?

Comment: Nice, but I disagree with one thing: I really don't wan't to prevent NPE. If anything goes wrong, it should blow. An error message is deemed to get undetected, an exception blows the build and that's strictly better than getting a nonsense.

Comment: Thanks! Note that if you want to blow up the build if there is a problem you can easily throw a custom exception instead of returning nonsense. It is probably easier to fix an exception which states `Error finding variable $name in file $file to determine version` instead of a generic NPE.